# Adding two Textformfields controller in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how to add two textformfields controllers in which int value is given?
when i was doing it showing me error saying that textediting controller can't be int.

```
child: ok != null ? Text('${okk1+ok1}',  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),) :Text(""),
```

first textformfield:-

```
Container(
                        height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/12,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3 ,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _hire,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(7),
                          ],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          onChanged: (str) {
                            setState(() {
                              okk = _advance.text as int;
                              ok1 =int.parse(_hire.text);
                            });
                            print(ok1);
                          },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(

                            labelText: '',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onSaved: (String value) {
                            // This optional block of code can be used to run
                            // code when the user saves the form.
                          },
                          validator: (String value) {
                            return value.contains('@')
                                ? 'Do not use the @ char.'
                                : null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

second textformfield:-

```
Container(
                        height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/12,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3 ,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _advance,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(7),
                          ],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                          onChanged: (str) {
                          setState(() {
                           ok = _advance.text;
                           okk1 =int.parse(_advance.text);
                            });
                          print(okk1);
                            },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: '',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onSaved: (String value) {
                            // This optional block of code can be used to run
                            // code when the user saves the form
                          },
                          validator: (String value) {
                            return value.contains('@')
                                ? 'Do not use the @ char.'
                                : null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

these are the textformfield controllers for two textformfield in which data is 45 and 5 but in string because controllers text is in string format and i want to add these two controllers and the result would be 50.

Comment: can you tell me what types are okk1 and ok1. also what are the 2 fields you want to add

Comment: Please provide more code than this. I'm not even seeing a texteditingcontroller in this code.

Comment: @SravanKumar these are the textformfield controllers for two textformfield in which data is 45 and 5 but in string because controllers text is in string format and i want to add these two controllers and the result would be 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them like this.

If `x1` and `x2` are two textcontrollers.

`var result = int.parse(x1.text) + int.parse(x2.text)`

Comment: x1 is 25 and x2 is 25 and with this method result showing is 2525.

Comment: didn't you use int.parse() ?

Comment: ok != null ? Text("${int.parse(_hire.text)}" + "${int.parse(_advance.text)}",  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),) :Text(""),

Comment: Text widget assumes variables as strings and is doing string concatenation.  
Try to add outside the text widget and use the result in the Text widget